# Is it safe to restore the phone.apk from a stock Samsung ROM to CM9?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, restore, titanium-backup

I was using the stock Samsung ROM on my Samsung S2 i9100. Changed over to Siyah Kernel and then made the leap to CyanogenMod 9.

Although I prefer and appreciate the myriad settings and usability of CM, there are a couple of issues where I preferred the functionality of the stock ROM:

1. The phone.apk - not just the dialer, but the incoming call screen
   and the large size buttons to answer a call or to bring up the
   keypad etc. I know I can use an alternate dialer like DialerOne or dwContacts but that doesn't help me to change the incoming call screen.
2. Pressing the physical home button to answer a call. There are times
   when it's exceedingly difficult to use the onscreen slider and a
   press to answer the call is far easier.
3. FM Radio - although Spirit Radio works as an alternative.

For items 1&2, can I overwrite the existing phone.apk and contacts.apk with the previous ones that I have backed up using Titanium Backup to return this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is usually "No."  The framework changes introduced with manufacturers' UI overlays (Samsung's TouchWiz in the case of your Galaxy S II)  most likely make the stock apps like Phone, Contacts, Calendar, etc. incompatible with custom ROMs like CyanogenMod ROM that are based on AOSP (Android Open Source Project).

Comment: Would you know of some way to restore similar functionality @Chahk?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  Although I imagine there are many 3rd-party apps out there that would help with [customizing the incoming call screen](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=incoming+call+screen).

Comment: Have tried some, not all. Don't work reliably per my experience.